# Parse Push Notification is not working properly see detail prob. below

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Friends, I am using parse.com as my backend. Now when I try to send push notifications using parse.com's website, all pushes will be sent successfully. But when I try to send pushes from my app code to a channel named "a" nothing is happening.

Below is my class code:

```
    public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        Button b, c;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);


            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
            c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                    push.setChannel("amar");
                    push.setMessage("The Giants just scored! It's now 2-2 against the Mets.");
                    push.sendInBackground();
                }
            });
            c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("a");
                }
            });

        } 
}
```

When I click on button b from the 1st emulator to send a push notification to the second emulator in which I installed my app and subscribed to channel "a" successfully, nothing is happening. The push notification is not received on the other emulator.

Comment: guys push.setChannel("amar") is not their it's push.setChannel("a");

Comment: Do you have Client Push enabled? To check this, go to parse.com, select your app, go to the settings page and then check the setting for "Client Push" in the Push settings.

Comment: really really  thanks to you my friend  i am working on this from last 12 hour continuously to find error, But error is not their error is in parse setup it's really annoyed me  , now this topic will help others who are finding error in code ,hole heartly thanks a lot now i can go to sleep :)